# How to programatically create a user in Joomla 4.x

Tags: joomla-4.x

In Joomla 3.x I used to create a user object with

```
$user = clone(JFactory::getUser());
```

(which I would then bind to an array of data, and then call save() on it), but JFactory::getUser() is deprecated now.

What is the new way of creating a new blank user object?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance here, but is `clone()` a function defined within Joomla?  I mean, PHP has [object cloning](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) which has been mentioned at [What is the purpose of cloning JUri in the CMSApplication route method?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23335/12352).  However, I'm not able to find any documentation on the technique that you are implementing.  Can you share any information that you have on that?  Oh wait, are you just using unneeded parentheses and smashing the magic method into the parentheses?

Comment: Is this question resolved by [Replacement of Factory::getUser($userid); in Joomla! 4.2](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/32502/12352) or [Non deprecated method in Joomla! 4 to load user by userid](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/31502/12352) or [Better way to rewrite method without deprecated JRequest](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/32615/12352) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Factory::getContainer()->get(UserFactoryInterface::class)->loadUserById(0);
```

Joomla uses this line for creating an empty User object around line 287 in `..\libraries\src\User\User.php`

```
// If the $id is zero, just return an empty User.
// Note: don't cache this user because it'll have a new ID on save!
if ($id === 0) {
    return Factory::getContainer()->get(UserFactoryInterface::class)->loadUserById($id);
}
```

You would need to add the appropriate statements for `Factory` and `UserFactoryInterface` in your code to get the object from the container by adding 'Use' statements, or use the following:

```
$user = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer()->get('user.factory')->loadUserById(0);
```

Comment: Terry, I'll leave [the acceptance of the edit](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13360) to you.

Comment: Good answer Irata, I have not checked this part yet in Joomla 4. However, it shows that Joomla still has design problems or questionable parts. My question would be, when I see this kind of code, why the Container needs a Factory to get an Interface and then a product (in this case, a User object). Sensibly, for me, it should look in the most complicated way, something like: `$app->getUserFactoryInterface()->create(User);` something of this sort…But anyway, we can always complicate things, and later someone can work on simplifying them…

Comment: @Zollie I just found that since Joomla 4.2 you can do a simple $this->getCurrentUser()  to get the User object by adding a 'use Joomla\CMS\User\CurrentUserTrait;' statement to your class. It is already available in BaseDatabaseModel and HtmlView classes.

Comment: Yes, I have also checked these few days ago and there are few other useful, short approaches too as I saw. So things are moving and improving :)